# Shell script to accept user input and change string in a text file and appending and repeating the same text in a separate file.

Tags: bash, shell

I have a certain mix of text and numerals let's say :

```
God is very 1234  and strong
He listens to us all day long
And teaches us to do what's right
But nobody knows 1234  what He does at night.
```

I want to write a shell script which takes user input from keyboard and replaces the numerical bit and copies the updated text in a separate file and repeats this process so that a text file is created which contains this text multiple times appended one below other with the numerical bit replaced upon each user input.

Comment: It should be easy to do with `sed`. Append the result to the new file with `>>` output redirection.

Comment: Sorry for not posting what I tried already, what I was actually stuck on was getting repeated inputs from the user, was not sure how to make use of the while loop. and initiate the whole replacement and copy each time a new input was given Thanks for help.

Comment: `while true; do read -r string; code that uses $string; done`

Comment: This is really basic shell scripting. SO also isn't a tutoring service, you're supposed to know the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` to achieve what you request. You may see below simple script to read a numeric from keyboard, and replace it into your `file_orig`. And append every output to `file` in the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input a numeric:"
read num

cat file_orig | awk -v aa=$num -v FPAT="[1-9]" '{ sub(/[0-9]+/,aa); print $0}' >> file
```